# The PostLinks table is not sanitized in the Data Explorer

Tags: bug, data-explorer

In the Data Explorer, there is the table `PostLinks`. This table contains the inter-relationships between posts that reference each other.

In the data dumps in Stack Exchange Data explorer, the data is 'sanitized' to remove deleted posts, but, this table is not sanitized, it seems, so there are links to posts which do not exist.

In essence, the relationships are broken in the data.

Here are the results of [the "missing query"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/336313/postlinks-that-point-to-missing-posts):

```
select LinkTypeId, count(*)
from PostLinks
where postId not in (select Id from Posts)
group by LinkTypeId
```

> ```
> LinkTypeId        
> ---------- ------ 
> 1          274032 
> 3          61863  
>
> (2 row(s) returned)
> ```

Comment: This is useful information because in part, it identifies the posts that were closed as duplicate of deleted posts, before a check to prevent the deletion of duplicate targets was implemented. It's questionable why the table includes links between two posts where _both_ are deleted.

Comment: This might be on purpose. There are references in other tables (Votes, for example) to deleted post ids.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Hmm... that makes it hard to locate "real" duplicates without joining to either the PostHistory for the most recent status and/or the Posts table too, making "big" queries very hard to accomplish. Still, you may be right, but that would suck for my purposes right now ;-)