# Update the names of questions given in "naked" links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

If I post a link to another question on the same Stack Exchange site, the name of the question is automatically rendered. For example,

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites
```

comes out as

[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

This is quite handy. However, when the title of the referenced question is changed, the displayed question title does not. When question titles are significantly changed but still linked, this can create some confusion.

Can the link names be automatically updated with edits to the title(s) of the linked question(s)?

Comment: This sounds expensive. FWIW, *any* edit to the post with the link should refresh the text.

Comment: +1 never knew they weren't updated. **For anyone wanting an example**: see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title?rq=1). In the blockquote, it says `Stack Exchange Sandbox`, but the current title is `Stack Exchange Data Explorer`

Comment: @Shog9 I figured it would take some work.

Comment: Maybe making the poor community bot do it would the way, but I never minded the old titles. Anyhow, +1.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Most of the time, the post being linked has something to do with the post being written (not so in your example).  In this case, updating terminology in the link  (Sandbox became Data Explorer) but *not* in the rest of the body would be worse than keeping everything as it was at the time of writing. Instead of "Ah, the SEDE used to be called Sandbox" a reader's reaction would be "What is this Sandbox he's talking about?"

Answer (score 6):

Although [NormalHuman makes a valid point in his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261269/245360), and I do understand the excessive need for resources to go over every post to edit, I still think this is very useful.

I do wonder if a bump is necessary after the edit or that is can be done behind the scenes, since it doesn't actually update the post code. (I don't actually want to, but that might take away the worry of 'unsupervised post updates')

Despite all the issues and performance implications, please implement this. It has more benefits than drawbacks in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bad idea to me: another user's edit to a different post would change the text of **your** post, with your name under it — without anyone checking that the change makes sense.

I sometimes use the title of a question I link to as a part of a sentence, for example to point out to someone that  [The PostLinks table is not sanitized in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260676/postlinks-is-not-sanitized). I don't want an edit to that question to break my sentence.

Even if the title is not a part of a sentence, my decision to include it in my post was made *on the basis of what the title was at the time of writing*. If it was different, perhaps I would not want to include it, inserting my own link text instead.

Unsupervised, automatic changes of text should be avoided.

Comment: I think that the cases you discuss - while valid - are only a small minority of all cases in which this would be a problem.

Comment: If you knew it might be different you'd insert the link text anyway, so it wouldn't matter. You're also over emphasising your "ownership" of the post. Once you've posted something it's effectively the community's.