Last Data Dump has various objects that point to posts that do not exist
As I was working with the last SE data dump, I noticed that there are PostLinks that reference posts that do not exist.
As an example, in opensource.meta PostLinks.xml there is a row:
<row Id="330" CreationDate="2015-06-25T20:35:59.847" PostId="130" RelatedPostId="93" LinkTypeId="1" />

However, when I look in the Posts.xml file, there are no search results for Id="93".
A quick query in SEDE shows that it is pointing to a deleted question.
SELECT *
FROM PostsWithDeleted
WHERE Id = 93

The same situation occurs with PostId in Votes.xml and AcceptedAnswerId in Posts.xml. Here is a quick SEDE query to demonstrate the latter: https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/1853165
I believe either deleted posts should be included in the data dump, or the PostLinks should not include links to deleted posts.
Edit: I also noticed a similar situation for Badges in Mathematics. They are pointing to Users that do not exist. https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1853349
Edit2: Also in Mathematics: a post owned by a user id that does not exist: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1853355/
Edit3: There is a user that is in Mathematics SEDE but not in the dump. User Id 1308569 is available in SEDE, but I can't find it in the dump. cat Users.xml | grep 'Id="1308569"' returns nothing.

remember that both data-dump and SEDE refresh aren't based of a static source.  The views / queries run against a live database (IIRC against the secondary in the DAG), one by one and are not guarded by a transaction of any kind, let alone a read isolated one. On the edge of producing a dump / refresh you wil find data inconsistencies, caused by either pure "luck" or because a batch job was running at the same time. That type of data mishaps should resolve itself with the next dump / refresh. Leaves "regular" issues which exist as well and are by-design at this stage.

Votes.xml is by-design having the vote records for deleted posts as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354977/the-votes-table-doesnt-have-the-votes-for-deleted-posts-does-it

bug report on PostLinks: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260676/the-postlinks-table-is-not-sanitized-in-the-data-explorer

@rene Is there any existing report about the Comments file entirely missing the ContentLicense column? I can't seem to find it by searching.

@Maxwell175  not that I know of.

I think it's nice to have this data for archival value. Even if it's doesn't reflect a coherent database state, one may potential reference these ID references against each other, or data from other sources (such as previous releases), so they're still carrying information. They're an annoying case to handle when importing this into a real database, but I'd rather that annoyance than losing the information.

This change has been made. Please see this post for more details on other fixes and changes related to data dumps.
